# Write Python list of lists row wise to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a list like this

```
[[1.75], [4.75]]
[[2.5], [2.5]]
[[3.5], [3.5]]
[[4.0], [4.0]]
```

I want to write this to a csv file like

```
1.75, 4.75
2.5, 2.5
3.5, 3.5
4.0, 4.0
```

When I tried using `writerows` method of `csv` module it is saved as

```
1.75
4.75
2.5
2.5
3.5
3.5
4.0
4.0
```

Comment: Why is each value in itself a list? Unwrap those so you get `[1.75, 4.75]`…?!

Comment: Assuming that you are using `writerow` property of a `csv.writer` object, and that you are doing `for row in your_array:`, you can use `[l[0] for l in row]` as the argument to `writerow`. (Actually I see that you say you are doing `writerows` but at least you *can* do `writerow` in a loop even if you are not currently doing so; it would be possible of course to put this into a generator expression and use `writerows` instead of a `for` loop, but there probably isn't a huge advantage in this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpack each row into a flat list.

```
import csv

my_list = [
    [[1.75], [4.75]],
    [[2.5], [2.5]],
    [[3.5], [3.5]],
    [[4.0], [4.0]],
    ]

with open("my.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for row in my_list:
        writer.writerow([l[0] for l in row])
```

Or if preferred, the `for` loop could be replaced with a generator expression so that you can use `writerows` as you are currently doing:

```
    writer.writerows([l[0] for l in row] for row in my_list)
```

Comment: What to do if there are more than one element is there in list.

Comment: @user567879 Then instead of `[l[0] for l in row]` you could use `[i for l in row for i in l]` - this will flatten a list of lists even if there are more than one element in each one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
import csv

lst = [[[1.75], [4.75]],
       [[2.5], [2.5]],
       [[3.5], [3.5]],
       [[4.0], [4.0]]]

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows([[x[0] for x in lst] for line in lst])
```

Alternatively, you can flat your list by using `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
...
w.writerows([list(chain(*line)) for line in lst])
```